# How to unselect an item in a select box?

Tags: html, select

I have an easy question for you today.  I have a select box that enables the user to select multiple items.  Also, when the user returns to the page, he can see which items he selected and unselect them if necessary. The trouble is that when I try to unselect, the selection just turns gray; it does NOT unselect.

```
<select name="MySelect" multiple>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3" selected="selected">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

So, when the element above renders to the page, I have no way to unselecting the option. The value is STILL getting passed to the form.

Any help?

Comment: Is using jQuery an option for you?

Comment: Yes, but no. I don't want to use jQuery here on this page.

Comment: not sure what the issue is, but shouldn't your select have multiple="multiple"? This may or may not be contributing to the issue, just taught id highlight it. do you have a sample where we can see the problem?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can deselect options in a multi-value select list by ctrl-clicking it.

Comment: I feel dumb after reading this ... Thanks. Btw, for anyone looking for it too. You can remove prop `selected` using jQuery (if you need it to be an external action)

Comment: Ctrl + ⌘-Click on Windows within a Mac VM ;)

Comment: Can some1 provide programmatic solution plz

Comment: @Sami Sure.  You'll find that that question has been [asked and answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12802739/deselect-selected-options-in-select-menu-with-multiple-and-optgroups).

Answer (score 3):

You can use JS object to memorize the status of a row and click action on select (JQuery).

```js
$('[name=MySelect]').click(function(e) {
  var i = this.selectedIndex;
  if (this.options[i].selectedOld == true) {
    this.options[i].selected = false;
    this.options[i].selectedOld = false;
  } else {
    this.options[i].selectedOld = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="MySelect" multiple>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3" selected="selected">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Sometimes we need to use a single-select field to prevent multiple selections, but we also need to unselect an option. This solution supports this workflow.