# Deselect selected options in select menu with multiple and optgroups

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to with a click of a link to be able to deselect all pre-selected options in a select menu with multiple select enable and with option groups.

Here is an example of the menu:

```
<select name="ddBusinessCategory" id="ddBusinessCategory" class="f1" style="width:280px;height:200px" multiple="multiple">
<option value="">Select One</option>
<optgroup label="Abrasives" style="background:#F5F5F5;border-bottom:1px #EEE solid">
<option value="4" selected="selected">Abrasives</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Abstracters" style="background:#F5F5F5;border-bottom:1px #EEE solid">
<option value="5">Abstracters</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Abuse Information &amp; Treatment Centers" style="background:#F5F5F5;border-bottom:1px #EEE solid">
<option value="6" selected="selected">Abuse Information &amp; Treatment Centers</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Accountants" style="background:#F5F5F5;border-bottom:1px #EEE solid">
<option value="7">Accountants</option>
<option value="2672">Certified Public Accountants - </option>
<option value="2673">Public Accountants - </option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Accounting Services" style="background:#F5F5F5;border-bottom:1px #EEE solid">
<option value="8">Accounting Services</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Acoustical Materials - Wholesale &amp; Manufacturers" style="background:#F5F5F5;border-bottom:1px #EEE solid">
<option value="9">Acoustical Materials - Wholesale &amp; Manufacturers</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

You will see two are selected.. I want to be able to deselect these preselected ones.

DONT want to use jquery, just want to use javascript

Many thanks for your assistance.

neojakey

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The following function should loop through all the options and unselect them.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" onclick="clearSelected();">clear</a>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
 function clearSelected(){
    var elements = document.getElementById("ddBusinessCategory").options;

    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
      elements[i].selected = false;
    }
  }
```

**EDIT**:

I don't endorse putting the event handler directly on the element. If you have the option, give the element some type of id/name and bind the event handler in your JavaScript code.

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3ZWPA/1/)**

Answer (score 33):

Would it not be simpler to just use?:

```
document.getElementById("ddBusinessCategory").value = "";
```

Comment: this should be the answer

Comment: This works for me, but if there is an option with value of "", then it would select that one.  Perhaps something obscure would be better (eg. ...value = "#$~";)

Comment: ddBusinessCategory.value = '';

Answer (score 14):

You don't need any loops.  The selectedIndex property "[Sets or returns the index of the selected `<option>` element in the collection (starts at 0)](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_select_options.asp)".
Indexing starts at 0 so if you set it to -1 none are selected.  (setting to 0 would leave the first option selected.)

```
function clearSelected(w){
  document.getElementById(w).selectedIndex = -1;
}
<a href="#" onclick="clearSelected('ddBusinessCategory');">clear</a>
```

Comment: This is the best answer as it is short, understandable and error proof. The other answer where the value is set to an empty string does not always work, because when there is an option with value of "", then it would select that one.

Answer (score 9):

You could simplify the code from Chase with the javascript property "selectedOptions"

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" onclick="clearSelected();">clear</a>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function clearSelected(){
    var elements = document.getElementById("ddBusinessCategory").selectedOptions;

    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
      elements[i].selected = false;
    }
  }
```

In this case you do a loop with the already selected options and not all options.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using jquery you can do (i know the person who asked this is expecting a js answer but this might help someone)

```
$('#someid').find($('option')).attr('selected',false)
```

Comment: This may have been correct in 2014, but currently this won't update the UI (the options will still be visually selected).  You need to use .prop instead (and get rid of the unnecessary call to $ within the find function:  $('#someid').find('option').prop('selected',false)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about < IE8:

```
var checkedElements = document.querySelectorAll("#ddBusinessCategory :checked");

​for(var i = 0, length = checkedElements.length; i < length; i++) {
    checkedElements[i].selected = false;
}​
```

If you don't care about < IE9

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("#ddBusinessCategory :checked"), function(el) { el.selected = false });
```

Use the answer from Chase if you want to support IE7, IE6, FF3 and earlier or feel it's easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to loop through only the selected options, I suggest a while loop.

```
var elements = document.getElementById("ddBusinessCategory").selectedOptions;
while (elements.length > 0)
{
    elements[0].selected = false;
}
```

The answer by Michel Sahli will not work when there are multiple selections, because as you progress through the for loop the value of `elements.length` changes.

That said, the .selectedOptions attribute is a bit troublesome (see [Is selectedOptions broken or...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711767/is-selectedoptions-broken-or)) so probably not worth whatever tiny savings you get by only looping through selected options.

Answer (score 0):

Once you select the option elements from the DOM in an object however you do that, 
(I will pretend they all have a class name) just remove the attribute:

**The Answer:**

```
options = document.getElementsByClassName('optionsClassName');

for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
  options[i].removeAttribute('selected');
}
```

**The Reason:** HTML reads to see if a selected attribute exists.  You can just have "selected" as an attribute without any value, and it will assume that option is selected.  So, it works if you remove the attribute. Selecting will insert a new "selected" attribute.  No worry.