# JS Code to remove selected options works with Firefox but not IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

My code (found with this topic : [Deselect selected options in select menu with multiple and optgroups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12802739/deselect-selected-options-in-select-menu-with-multiple-and-optgroups)) :

```
function clearSelected(id) {
    var select = document.getElementById(id);
    for(var i = 0, len = select.options.length; i < len; i++){
        select.options[i].selected = false;
    }
}
```

Where id = id of the Select Element that contain list of options.

If I run the script on Firefox, everything is ok, all selected options are unselected. But when I run with IE 11, it doesn't work. Any Idea of what's wrong ?
I tried to run it with console, but I haven't any error and IE is correctly identifying Select and Options. Let me know if you need any further info.

**EDIT** : The Options content of focused Select is dynamically generated in javascript. May be this is not compatible with IE ?

```
<select name="listechoix3Alt" id="listechoix3AltId" size="9" class="formAA" onChange='filltheselect(this.name, this.value)' style="width:330px; display: none;">
                <script language="javascript">
                    for (i=0; i<art7.length; i++)
                    document.write("<option value=\"" +art7[i][0]+ "\">" +art7[i][1]+ "</option>");
                </script>
            </select>
```

**EDIT2** : I've made some additional tests :

```
<select name="listechoix3Alt" id="listechoix3AltId" size="9" class="formAA" style="width:330px; display: none;">
                <option value="n0">CDS Fermé</option>
                <option value="n1">Compte bloqué</option>
                <option value="n2">Pas de place sur le planning</option>
                <option value="n3">Pas de produit disponible dans le délai attendu par le client</option>
            </select>
            <a href="#" onclick="clearSelected('listechoix3AltId');">clear</a>
```

When I click on clear with Firefox, working fine. With IE, nothing happens ! Make me crazy !

Comment: I don't understand your question, from the HTML provided you aren't using a `<select multiple>` so what is the expected behaviour of this code? Please also try writing your code as a snippet which reproduces the issue so we can compare across browsers easily

Comment: It's a Select without multiple, in this case I don't need multiple choice. If I click on the link clear, I would like to disable the selected option of the input. This is what's working on Firefox but not on IE.
If I put this code on http://jsfiddle.net/3ZWPA/30/ it's working on IE...